# Reference "Self" in aws cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cloud-init

I've got an EC2 resource defined in Cloudformation like so:

```
Resources:
  FooInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      blah: blah
      blah: blah
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource FooInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Is there a special variable/replacement string to reference "self" in that UserData cfn-init block instead of explicitly declaring `FooInstance`? It would help make definitions much more copypastable for my team.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. This would be a very nice add-on for both `UserData` and `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` parts, but AWS still doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks you!   I will submit a feature request, we'll see what comes of it.

Comment: @Eric Can you add the link to the feature request so we can follow it?